# Heterogeneous nucleation theory books or articles

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, nucleation

I'm looking for books or fundamental articles about the heterogeneous nucleation theory. I'd like to understand the main effects driving it, with concrete examples.

If you have any idea plz tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for liquid-vapor transitions, look for books dealing with *boiling heat transfer*.